# Quadrilateral and bisecting lines

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to establish that the lines joining the mid points of opposite sides of a quadrilateral bisect each other. I attempted using mid point theorem of triangles but I couldn't prove it

Comment: Use the midpoint theorem of triangles to show that the four midpoints are vertices of a parallelogram. The diagonal-bisecting property then follows immediately.

Comment: The midpoints form a parallelogram. The said lines are actually the diagonals of the parallelogram. They bisect each other.

Comment: @AchariSGanesha: You should write your understanding as an answer here, then accept it. That'll get your question out of the unanswered queue and prevent the StackExchange system from repeatedly reposting it.